# Scala: Appending an Element to a List

Tags: scala, list, collections

I have the following 2 code snippets; the first one gives me no trouble, but for the second one (appending to the list in a function), I'm getting an error message.  What's the difference between these 2, and how do I fix the second one?

This one works fine:

```
object MyApp extends App
{
    var myList = List.range (1, 6)
    myList ::= 6    
    println(myList)
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
def myFunc(list:List[Int]):Unit =
    {
        list ::= 10
    }


error: value ::= is not a member of List[Int]
        list ::= 10
             ^
one error found
```

Answer (score 7):

Variables marked with `var` are mutable and so can be reassigned. The `a ::= b` operator is simply [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) provided by the compiler **for `var` variables**. It performs the operation `a = b :: a`. Here is an example:

```
scala> var l1 = List(1,2,3)
l1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l1 ::= 4

scala> l1
res1: List[Int] = List(4, 1, 2, 3)

scala> val l2 = List(1,2,3)
l2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l2 ::= 4
<console>:9: error: value ::= is not a member of List[Int]
              l2 ::= 4
                 ^
scala> val l3 = 4 :: l2
l3: List[Int] = List(4, 1, 2, 3)
```

Passed parameters are not mutable so the `::=` operator cannot be used.

Comment: So, the error message "value ::= is not a member of List" is wrong, or at least not that helpful.  It should be saying something like list is immutable, and thus can't be assigned to.  I mean :: didn't suddenly stop being an operator that can be used on the List.

Comment: I suppose it could be more useful, but it isn't wrong. `::=` is never an element of `List` but it is translated to `a = b :: a` by the compiler.